# Using [(ngModel)] does not apply change in unit test for inputs inside ngFor

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm having trouble testing an Angular component that utilizes the two way `[(ngModel)]` binding on checkbox inputs inside an `ngFor`. It works just fine in the actual app. This is just a problem with the test.

Here's an example test that fails:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, fakeAsync, TestBed, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Component, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

describe('Example Test', () => {
  @Component({
    template: `
      <input *ngFor="let value of values"
             type="checkbox"
             class="checkbox-1"
             [(ngModel)]="value.isSelected"
             (change)="output.emit(values)">
    `,
    styles: [``]
  })
  class TestHostComponent {
    @Output() output: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    values = [
      { isSelected: true },
      { isSelected: true },
      { isSelected: true },
    ];
  }

  let testHost: TestHostComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestHostComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [FormsModule],
      declarations: [TestHostComponent],
      providers: []
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestHostComponent);
    testHost = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should change isSelected', fakeAsync(() => {
    const spy = spyOn(testHost.output, 'emit');
    fixture.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.checkbox-1')[0].click();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    tick();

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith([
      { isSelected: false }, // it fails because this is still true
      { isSelected: true },
      { isSelected: true },
    ]);
  }));
});
```

Using `[(ngModel)]` with a single input that's not in a loop works fine in a similar test. I've even logged the emitted value from `(ngModelChange)` and when the checkbox is clicked `$event` is `true` when it should really be `false`.

Any ideas?

Comment: I updated my question with a better example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like that method of performing a click isn't triggering change detection. Dispatching a change event on the checkbox instead gave the expected result:

```
it('should change isSelected', fakeAsync(() => {
    const spy = spyOn(testHost.output, 'emit');
    const checkbox = fixture.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.checkbox-1')[0];
    checkbox.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    tick();

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith([
        { isSelected: false }, // This is now false
        { isSelected: true },
        { isSelected: true },
    ]);
}));
```

Solution inspired by [this post](https://medium.com/@sevcsik/testing-ngmodel-in-angular-2-d9c79923f973).

**UPDATE:**

It looks like there's a need to wait for some controls to be initialized or registered on the CheckboxControlValueAccessor. If you modify the second `beforeEach()` to wait for one cycle after creating the component, the original test code works:

```
beforeEach(fakeAsync(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestHostComponent);
    testHost = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    tick();
}));
```

See [this Github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17104) for the full answer/explanation.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. However, it seems like there might be a bug somewhere if Angular's change detection is not triggered from click events in tests. The real behavior I want to test is that clicking the checkbox results in a change. This seems like the best option right now so I'll mark it as the solution.

Comment: Good point, I did a little poking around and found what I believe is the right answer/explanation. See this link: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17104. I tried it out by adding fakeAsync and tick to the second beforeEach function and your original test worked. I'll edit my answer to include this.

Comment: Not for nothing - I was having similar issue.  Except that I was trying to change value from the other direction, programmatically and testing to see if the input had changed.   Tests failed until I added fakeAsync/tick

Comment: Had the same issue, and it turns out that removing [(ngModel)], and update value.isSelected within the (change) is working.